# Fade in my background-image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

a few of this question is already in StackOverflow but none of the answers fixed my problem. The closest I got was my background image changing with fade in but I get a white flash before the transition.

The page is a weather API that gets the current weather in your location and changes the background accordingly. The background image that I want to fade is the one that comes after I get the weather.

I tried a lot, but nothing seems to work. I am new in JS and Jquery. PS. if you see a loading animation forever is because you still did not accept to find your location.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getCurrentLocation(callback) {
        if (!navigator.geolocation) return;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            url = ('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&units=metric&appid=b464bb8dd84e7e7d36103593a472ae9a');
            callback(url);
        });

    }

    function celciusToFahrenheit(celcius) {
        var fahrenheit = celcius * (9 / 5) + 32;
        return fahrenheit;
    }

    getCurrentLocation(function(currLocMap) {
        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            var html = "";
            var flag = 0;

            if (json.weather[0].id == 800) {
                // clear
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("http://hires.photospublic.com/PP51292613-Small-cloudy-formations-on-a-clear-sky.jpg")');
            } else if (json.weather[0].id > 800) {
                // clouds
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/158163/clouds-cloudporn-weather-lookup-158163.jpeg")');
            } else if (json.weather[0].id >= 700) {
                // fog
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/17579/pexels-photo.jpg")');
            } else if (json.weather[0].id >= 600) {
                //snow
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("http://pre10.deviantart.net/98d7/th/pre/i/2013/012/b/c/snowing_by_austriaangloalliance-d5r9ank.jpg")');
            } else if (json.weather[0].id >= 500) {
                //rainny
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("http://kingofwallpapers.com/rainy/rainy-019.jpg")');
            } else if (json.weather[0].id >= 300) {
                //light rain
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("http://kingofwallpapers.com/rainy/rainy-019.jpg")');
            } else if (json.weather[0].id >= 200) {
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/kids/photos/articles/Science/H-P/lightning-trees.jpg")');
            }

            html += '<button class="temp" id="link">'
            html += "<h1>" + Math.round(json.main.temp) + " °C </h1>";
            html += "</button>"

            html += "<h1>" + json.name + "</h1>";
            html += "<h3>" + json.weather[0].main + "</h3>";
            html += "<h3>" + json.weather[0].description + "</h3>";

            $("#data").on('click', '#link', function() {
                var buttonclick = "";
                if (flag == 0) {
                    buttonclick += "<h1>" + celciusToFahrenheit(Math.round(json.main.temp)) + " °F</h1>";
                    $("h1", $(this)).html(buttonclick);
                    flag = 1;
                } else if (flag == 1) {
                    buttonclick += "<h1>" + Math.round(json.main.temp) + " °C</h1>";
                    $("h1", $(this)).html(buttonclick);
                    flag = 0;
                }
            });

            $("#block").addClass("square");
            $("#data").html(html);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
button#link {
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

button#link:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

body {
    background: url("https://www.tomswallpapers.com/pic/201508/1366x768/tomswallpapers.com-28772.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#data {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.square {
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
    left: 40%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 35%;
    top: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Thanks to http://cssload.net/en/spinners/2 for the loading element!*/
.cssload-loader-inner {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 58px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 97px;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap {
    animation: cssload-spin 2300ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite;
    -o-animation: cssload-spin 2300ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite;
    -ms-animation: cssload-spin 2300ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-spin 2300ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite;
    -moz-animation: cssload-spin 2300ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 49px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    width: 97px;
}

.cssload-loader-line-wrap {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -o-border-radius: 100%;
    -ms-border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 97px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 97px;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: -57.5ms;
    -o-animation-delay: -57.5ms;
    -ms-animation-delay: -57.5ms;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -57.5ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: -57.5ms;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: -115ms;
    -o-animation-delay: -115ms;
    -ms-animation-delay: -115ms;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -115ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: -115ms;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: -172.5ms;
    -o-animation-delay: -172.5ms;
    -ms-animation-delay: -172.5ms;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -172.5ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: -172.5ms;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: -230ms;
    -o-animation-delay: -230ms;
    -ms-animation-delay: -230ms;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -230ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: -230ms;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: -287.5ms;
    -o-animation-delay: -287.5ms;
    -ms-animation-delay: -287.5ms;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -287.5ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: -287.5ms;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap:nth-child(1) .cssload-loader-line-wrap {
    border-color: rgb(234, 71, 71);
    height: 88px;
    width: 88px;
    top: 7px;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap:nth-child(2) .cssload-loader-line-wrap {
    border-color: rgb(234, 234, 71);
    height: 74px;
    width: 74px;
    top: 14px;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap:nth-child(3) .cssload-loader-line-wrap {
    border-color: rgb(71, 234, 71);
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    top: 20px;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap:nth-child(4) .cssload-loader-line-wrap {
    border-color: rgb(71, 234, 234);
    height: 47px;
    width: 47px;
    top: 27px;
}

.cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap:nth-child(5) .cssload-loader-line-wrap {
    border-color: rgb(71, 71, 234);
    height: 33px;
    width: 33px;
    top: 34px;
}

@keyframes cssload-spin {
    0%,
    15% {
        transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-spin {
    0%,
    15% {
        -o-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-spin {
    0%,
    15% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-spin {
    0%,
    15% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-spin {
    0%,
    15% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Weather</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="block" class="text-center">
        <div id="data">
            <!-- Thanks to http://cssload.net/en/spinners/2 for the loading element! -->
            <div class="cssload-loader-inner">
                <div class="cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap">
                    <div class="cssload-loader-line-wrap"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap">
                    <div class="cssload-loader-line-wrap"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap">
                    <div class="cssload-loader-line-wrap"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap">
                    <div class="cssload-loader-line-wrap"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap">
                    <div class="cssload-loader-line-wrap"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If your question is a follow up, you should link the previous question, to provide context. Also, note you are supposed to provide a [mcve]. In case you don't know how to translate *minimal* in current context, it means: *remove everything from your code that is irrelevant to the question being asked*. Since your question is about changing the background, the first thing you should remove (to make the question easier to answer) would be the content, only leaving the empty container that needs background changed (eventually with a `min-height: 100vh`).

Comment: what is the click handler on #data doing? Is it suppose to change a background?I am not seeing any click label for this div.Can you put all your codes in a pen for debugging?